# Silverlight app remote debugging via msvsmon.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, remote-debugging, silverlight-5.0

I have little problem with debugging silverlight app on a remote machine. I launched msvsmon.exe, added permissions, added my account to administrators group. But when I connect, I can't debug silverlight process, it's type is determined as native (please see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY6YX.png))

On local machine it works perfectly, I can attach to any silverlight process, and I want to do the same thing on a remote machine. 
Also on the remote machine is installed XP Service Pack 3 x86, on my machine I have Windows 7 Ultimate x64. I use VS 2010 and it's launched as administrator.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not working within a domain network, look here, http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2010/06/15/vs-remote-debugging-across-workgroups-or-domains.aspx

This helped me a lot.